# write the integer value of a file descriptor to a file

Tags: c, unix

Just testing out file descriptors. My aim is to open up a file stream with fopen and using fprintf write the file descriptors integer value back into the file to see what results im getting.

(I decided using fopen, fprintf etc) as it allowed me to write in variables, write() wouldn't allow it,

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  FILE *fp;

  fp = fopen("wow.txt", "w+");
  if (fp < 0)
    {
      printf("ERROR \n");
    }
  else
    {
      printf("we good \n");
    }

  fprintf(fp, "hi %p \n", fp);
}
```

Issue i am facing is, if i write %d for the fprintf statement...i get a compiler error. If i write %p, I get the address in RAM.

Is it possible to get the absolute integer value...like "3"

Comment: If you open a file, close it before you depart from the function.  And you get the file descriptor from a file stream (on POSIX) with `fileno(fp)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
FILE *fp;
```

is *not* a file descriptor, it's a file stream *pointer* and, as such, you need to treat it as a pointer.

A file *descriptor* is a small integer returned from one of the UNIXy calls like `open` or `creat`, while file *pointers* are sort of a level above that, assuming you're in an environment that even *has* descriptors.

In those environments, you can generally get at the underlying descriptor with something like:

```
int fd = fileno (fp);
```

The following complete program (under CygWin) shows this in action:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    FILE *fp = fopen ("wow.txt", "w+");
    if (fp < 0) {
        printf ("ERROR\n");
        return 1;
    }

    fprintf (fp, "fp=%p, fd=%d\n", fp, fileno (fp));
    fclose (fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling that with:

```
gcc -o testprog testprog.c
```

gives the output:

```
fp=0x800102a8, fd=3
```

Comment: Right, thanks for clearing that up, just read on fileno. Would you recommend that?

Comment: @Bobski, yes, I would, if you really want to know the file descriptor from a pointer. And, no apology needed, you caught me mid-edit when I was adding that advice - that happens quite a bit :-)

Comment: cheers anyway, just waiting a few more minutes as I can't mark your answer as solved as of yet due to time limit.